run /etc/rc.local after restarting systemd-networkd.service
platform: ubuntu 22.04
I am performing advance routing and and I have saved all the commands in the /etc/rc.local file.
the problem is once the systemd-networkd.service  is restarted, the routing table is going to be flushed and my routing including the static routes are removed and bring down the server connectivity.
is there any way to instruct the systemd-networkd.service  to run the /etc/rc.local once it is being restarted?
I'm using default netplan config.
the systemd-networkd.service  is being restarted once the packages are being upgraded.
Regards,

Since there are some major differences between Ubuntu 22.04 and 24.04 please pick one you want an answer for. The answer may be different for each.

eh you should have a rc-local.service. why not add that to the  systemd chain?

@David lets go with 22.04

@Rinzwind i have created the systemd chain to run after the systemd-networkd service restart. though, it seems that it qas not working

Do not tell me edit the question please.

I believe I've found the solution:
here it is:
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.d
vi /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.d/override.conf

[Service]
ExecStartPost=/etc/rc.local

systemctl daemon-reload

